# What is the guideline for adding snapin/Import modue in production environment?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to do IIS operations in powershell. Our customers may have windows 2008 R2 or Sp2.

Unfortunately in Windows 2008 Sp2 Webadministration is a snapin, while in R2 it is a module.

If our script is to be used in diff server in production environment, how to make sure that our script won't break in one of the machine?

Answer (score 2):

You can test the pssnapin existence:

```
if ( [bool]((Get-PSSnapin -Registered) -match 'Webadministration') )
{
  add-pssnapin Webadministration
}
else
{
   import-module Webadministration
}
```

You can test also the module existence:

[`bool]((get-module -ListAvailable) -match "Webadministration")`

Or you can test the OS using wmi:

```
 (gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem ).caption
```

and based on the caption value add pssnapin or mudule

Edit:

Fast way:

```
if (!(import-module Webadministration -ea silentlycontinue) #on error return $false
{
 add-pssnapin Webadministration
}
```

Comment: Easier way to get OS version: `[Environment]::OSVersion.Version` where 6.0 → Vista/2o08 and 6.1 → Win7/2008R2.